# UE4 не работает InputAxis

Tags: input, unreal-engine-4

В ProjectSettings создал свой Axis Mappings под названием MoveRight. В Blueprint не работет событие "InputAxis MoveRight". При попытке выветси от него что-нибудь, вообще ничего не выводит, хотя каждый кадр должно выводить сообщение на экран. Не понимаю, в чём проблема? Как заставить InputAxis работать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Такая же проблема, перебрал все найденные в инете методы решения, но ничего не помогло

Comment: Заскринь настройки input'а и то, где ты его вызываешь.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках проекта Maps&Modes. Пункт Default Pawn Class здесь можно выбрать блюпринт персонажа по умолчанию, в этом Блюпринте ваше событие "InputAxis MoveRight" будет работать.

Как заставить его работать в любом другом Блюпринте, я пока не знаю, гуглил эту тему и попал на этот вопрос.